# Normality of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

How is normality of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ reflected in the table that displays the operation on cosets ?

What I did: Let $G$ is a group of $8$ elements as $G= \mathbb{Z}_8$

And let $H$ be the subgroup $\{0,4\}$ . The cosets of $H$ can be found as, $$\{0,4\}, 1+\{0,4\}=\{1,5\}, 2+\{0,4\}=\{2,6\}, 3+\{0,4\}=\{3,7\}$$

Now the set of cosets can be converted in to a group as per the following table $\mathbb{Z}_8/\{0,4\}$ into a group. So the addition table will be,

[image]

The rule for constructing the cosets table is given by $\{2,6\}+\{3,7\}=\{1,5\}$ such that $\{2,6\}=2+\{0,4\}$ and $\{3,7\}=3+\{0,4\}$

You add cosets by adding their representatives --- in this case, $2$ and $3$ --- and attaching the sum to the subgroup --- in this case, $\{0,4\}$ :

$$\{2,6\}+\{3,7\}=(2+\{0,4\})+(3+\{0,4\})=(2+3)+\{0,4\}=5+\{0,4\}=\{1,5\}$$

So this means whatever element we can choose the resulting element will be in the same cosets. Hence from the Lemma it is said that the Subgroup H is normal in to the Cosets Table.

Comment: Perhaps you should compare a normal and a non-normal subgroup tables. For that you need to work with a non-abelian group, to begin with. I'd try with $\;S_3\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio According to Artin's Algebra book, we have to use cosets concepts to prove it